# Vba error somewhere in this code that it doesn't allow my code to run

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
 Dim CustNumber As String    
  Dim CustName As String    
  Dim CompanyName As String    
  Dim    CustPhoneNumb As String    
  Dim i As Long      
  CustNumber = Worksheets("OrderInvoice").Range("C10").Value    
  Sheets("CustomerList").Select
  FoundDatails = False    
  i = 1    
  For i = 1 To 100    
    Cells(i, 1).Select    
    If CustNumber = Trim(Cells(i, 1)) Then    
      CustName = Trim(Cells(i, 2))    
      CompanyName = Trim(Cells(i, 3))    
      CustPhoneNumb = Trim(Cells(i, 4))    
      FoundDatails = True    
      Exit For    
    Else    
      i = i    
    End If    
  Next      
  Sheets("OrderInvoice").Select      
  Range("C11:F11") = CustName    
  Range("I11:J11") = CustPhoneNumb    
  Range("C12:J12") = CompanyName    
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest putting some error trapping in the code to see what the error actually is. You also need to make sure that your change event is actually triggering.

Comment: sorry about that am new in the vacinity

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Select method of Range class failed via VBA...refering to the line below the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible answers. The most probable is that you should change:

`Cells(i, 1).Select` to 
`Sheets("CustomerList").Cells(i, 1).Select`

Others are - check whether you have values in the range variables and whether the sheets exists as named. Furthermore, use `Option Explicit` on top to make sure you write one idea better code.

Comment: How do i code vba to populate my form from my a list selection where my data is in another worksheet?

Comment: Hi. For this one I need the VBA code and a screenshot plus explanations concerning the names of the list you are using. This sounds like another question, so it is probably better to ask it separately. Just remember - format your code wisely, use `Option Explicit` and Ctrl+K in stackoverflow. Enjoy!